# How does one display a RawRes in a compose image?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-resources, coil

This probably is covered *somewhere*, but I was unable to find it in the docs / on SO, so I decided to ask:

I've tried this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RawImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @RawRes resource: Int,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit
) {
    AsyncImage(
        modifier = modifier,
        model = LocalContext.current.resources.openRawResource(resource),
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        contentScale = contentScale
    )
}
```

and this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun RawImage(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    @RawRes resource: Int,
    contentDescription: String? = null,
    contentScale: ContentScale = ContentScale.Fit
) {
    AsyncImage(
        modifier = modifier,
        model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current)
            .data(resource)
            .build(),
        contentDescription = contentDescription,
        contentScale = contentScale
    )
}
```

but so far, both of them don't seem to load the image, so I'm seeking any resources / gists / links that describe how to display a RawRes in Compose,
cheers!

Comment: Is there a requirement for it to be a raw resource rather than a `nodpi` drawable resource or an asset?

Comment: It is a .jpg image, so I believe so?

Comment: That’s no reason it couldn’t be either of those other options. A `nodpi` resource would be easiest so you wouldn’t need to use Coil, but Coil can load assets directly using the `file://` prefix for the URI.

Comment: managed to solve it with `nodpi`, would you mind posting the comment as an answer, so I may mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to use a raw resource, you can use a `drawable-nodpi` resource and load it as you would other image resources, which is simpler than trying to use a raw resource. `.jpg` files are valid drawable resources.